# Is map key generated in one machine cannot be used in another machine?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have an Android map view application. In order to view the mapview, I have generated a map key and has able to view Google map. When I install the same apk in another machine's emulator, the map is not showing. Why so? Is it because of the map key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because each debug.keystore of your ADT is associated with a unique Google Maps API key.

If you want to reuse this Google Maps API keys, simply copy you debug.keystore (locate in C:\Documents and Settings\YOUR_USERNAME\ .android) and replace your debug.keystore in other PC with this one.

Comment: So, can you please tell me what's problem in the first time you tried? :)

Comment: I have to clean the project and then build it